# Testing strongSelf guard in Swift

Tags: swift, unit-testing, code-coverage

I've been using the following pattern for a while:

```
closure() { [weak self] in 
    guard let strongSelf = self else {
        return
    }
    // Do some real work here
}
```

Is there any way to test the return statement inside the guard?  Or am I just foolishly chasing 100% code coverage?

Also, I realize that I could just use an if/let instead of a guard/let.  My question is about the guard/let scenario.

Comment: Set up a testcase where object that owns this closure is used then released, then run this closure and check that it didn't perform the rest of its function. Or instead, you could try to just write good code without diluting your codebase in chase of arbitrary metric goals.

Comment: What are you using this pattern for? Is it for breaking strong reference cycles?

Comment: @Deyton Yes, it's for breaking strong reference cycles.  The actual code I implement is more substantial and uses the Reactive framework, but this code example should function the same way.

Comment: I agree; create a test case if you can, but recognize that it's sometimes impractical (defensive `guard`, Swift 3 `precondition`/`dispatchPrecondition`, `fatalError`, unsatisfiable `default` clauses in `switch` statements, etc.). If not immediately obvious, I just add a comment to that effect, so at least when I click through to the code from my coverage report, I know that that the lack of coverage was anticipated. FYI, [this is interesting](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/2016/02/02/partial-functions-part-two-catching-precondition-failures.html), though impractical, IMHO.

Comment: @Rob Thanks - I have a test case to make sure the object disappears when it should.  I've been just commenting it like you mentioned, but I was hoping someone out there smarter then me had a better solution.  :)